# What's wrong with my plot?

Tags: pgfplots

I have this code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
      symbolic x coords={Germany,Spain,UK},
      xtick=data,
      axis x line=bottom,
      axis y line=left,
      x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=east},
      ymin=0,
      enlarge x limits={abs=0.6cm},
      ymax=110,
      ytick={0,10,...,100},
      ybar=6pt,
      bar width=14pt,
      ylabel=\% blablabla
    ]
    \addplot[fill=blue] coordinates {
        (Germany,10)
        };
    \addplot[fill=red] coordinates {
         (Spain,30)       
        };
    \addplot[fill=yellow] coordinates {
         (UK,40)       
        };    
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I want to draw a plot for each country with different color. However as you can see "Spain" and "UK" are not printed and the plots are too far away. How can I fix this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). Also, can you please edit the title of the question which describes the actual problem so that it may be of help to others in the future (so that it is easier to locate if someone else has a similar question).

Comment: Follow up Question: [How to customize only one coord?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/221010/how-to-customize-only-one-coord).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`xtick=data` only uses the first `\addplot` command for determining the tick positions. You can get the desired result by using `xtick={Germany,Spain,UK}`

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
      symbolic x coords={Germany,Spain,UK},
      xtick={Germany,Spain,UK},
      axis x line=bottom,
      axis y line=left,
      x tick label style={rotate=45},
      ymin=0,
      enlarge x limits={abs=0.5cm},
      ymax=110,
      ytick={0,10,...,100},
      ybar=6pt,
      bar width=14pt,
      ylabel=\% blablabla     
    ]
    \addplot[bar shift=0pt,fill=blue] coordinates {
        (Germany,10)
        };
    \addplot[bar shift=0pt,fill=red] coordinates {
         (Spain,30)       
        };
    \addplot[bar shift=0pt,fill=yellow] coordinates {
         (UK,40)       
        };    
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]